# Значение const брать из id, а не задавать?

Tags: javascript

Есть

```js
const TEXT = "Transfer: Вопрос: почему сегодня такая плохая погода<br><br> Ответ: Мы сами не знаем<br>Вопрос: хорошо спасибо<br><br>";
function onClick() {
  const QUESTIONS = TEXT.match(/вопрос:.*?(?=<br>)/gi);
  const QUESTIONS_HTML = QUESTIONS.join("<br>");
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = QUESTIONS_HTML;
}
```

```html
<textarea id=text> </textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<div id="question"></div>
```

Который работает от заданного значение TEXT;

Как сделать так что бы значение TEXT бралось из поля textarea?

```js
const TEXT = document.getElementById('text').value;

function onClick() {
  const QUESTIONS = TEXT.match(/вопрос:.*?(?=<br>)/gi);
  const QUESTIONS_HTML = QUESTIONS.join("<br>");
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = QUESTIONS_HTML;
  }
```

```html
<textarea id=text> </textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<div id="question"></div>
```

Выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что, когда выполняется код document.getElementById('text'), то textarea хранит пустую строку, и регулярное выражение, которое вы используете на пустой возвращает null, поэтому и ошибка. Чтоб исправить ошибку, вам нужно брать значение непосредственно во время клика по кнопке.

```js
const TEXTElement = document.getElementById('text');

function onClick() {
  const TEXT = TEXTElement.value;
  const QUESTIONS = TEXT.match(/вопрос:.*?(?=<br>)/gi);
  const QUESTIONS_HTML = QUESTIONS.join("<br>");
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = QUESTIONS_HTML;
  }
```

```html
<textarea id=text> </textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<div id="question"></div>
```

Теперь если ввести в textarea строку, которая подходит под регулярное выражение, то ошибок не будет.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а как сделать так что бы функция выполнялась не по клику а по onkeyup

Comment: @jonghi, да, так же, только слушать событие 'keyup' вместо 'click'

Comment: Только событие keyup будет возникать каждый раз, когда пользователь поднял клавишу, а значит регулярное выражение в вашем примере может вернуть null, что вызовет такую же ошибку, поэтому делайте проверку на null

Comment: Ввод будет происходить только посредством ctrl+V, ручного ввода не планируется.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за информацию. Пытался сделать onkeyup="onClick()" в textarea, функция не реагирует на текст

Comment: @jonghi, если не будет возникать 'keyup', то есть еще событие 'input', которое возникает каждый раз, когда значение в форме изменяется

Comment: Так же не забывайте делать проверку на null после регулярного выражения, ведь, если выполнение функции завершится с ошибкой, хоть один раз, то браузер ее вызывать уже не будет

Comment: А как ее сделать? можете подсказать

Comment: **const QUESTIONS = TEXT.match(/вопрос:.*?(?=<br>)/gi);
if (QUESTIONS) {
  const QUESTIONS_HTML = QUESTIONS.join("<br>");
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = QUESTIONS_HTML;
}** - примерно так